# Make math symbol bold and non-italic simultaneously in latex

Tags: math-mode, equations, amsmath, bm

How to make a math symbol bold as well as non-italic in the math-mode of latex. I have been trying to both bold and non-italicize `x` and `\theta` using the following minimum-working-example. `x` can be bold or non-italicized but cannot be both. While `\theta` can only be bold but neither non-italicized nor both. What is wrong with the code and how should one do it?

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}

\begin{document}
    \begin{equation*}
    x ~ \bm{x} ~ {\rm x} ~ \bm{\rm x}
\end{equation*}

\begin{equation*}
    \theta ~ \bm{\theta} ~ {\rm \theta} ~ \bm{\rm \theta}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\bm x` produces a bold italic x. As to Greek letters, you have the `upgreek` package.  However, I would advise against having both italic and upright Greek letters in a document. It would be quite confusional, in my opinion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple `\mathbf` and package `upgreek` for upright Greek letters (see Bernard's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/417151/make-math-symbol-bold-and-non-italic-simultaneously-in-latex#comment1043015_417151)) are your friends:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\begin{document}
\[
  (x, \theta) \Rightarrow (\mathbf{x}, \mathbf{\uptheta})
\]
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]